# Calculus Made Easy, 1998 edition, pg 63: I don't understand why $dV/dr = 3\times \pi\times r^2$ when h = r and varies with r

Tags: calculus

Source : Calculus Made Easy, 1998 edition, pg 63 [see [here](https://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/bachillerato/libros/%5BThompson,Gardner%5DCalculus%20Made%20Easy(1998).pdf) for a link to the book].

I understand the solution to problem (3), when $h = r$, and $h$ remains constant: $$dV/dr = 2\times \pi\times r^2.$$

However, I don't understand where the $3$ comes from in the third solution, when $h = r$ and $h$ varies with $r$:
$$dV/dr = \boxed{3}\times \pi\times r^2?$$

Comment: Very few people are going to have a copy of this to hand. You should copy out all relevant context (use pictures only when really necessary)

Comment: Please provide a scan of the page, or write it down.

Comment: The text is comparing $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \pi r^2 h \bigg|_{h=r}$ to $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \pi r^2 r = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \pi r^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume $V$ of a right circular cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$ is given by
$$
V = \pi r^2 h.
$$

The tasks are to determine the rate of change of volume with respect to radius in different contexts:

- $h$ remains constant
- $h=r$ (hence, varies with it)

(In the text, we are also asked to solve for certain quantities algebraically, but we need not concern ourselves with that here.)

---

When $h$ is treated as a constant, its value can be substituted in *after* the derivative is calculated.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}r} 
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \Bigl[ \pi r^2 h \Bigr] 
= \pi h \, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \Bigl[ r^2 \Bigr]
= 2\pi r h.
$$
In this case, we have a growing radius but a fixed height, and we happen to check in at the moment when the radius matches the height. Since we're considering the situation where $h = r$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}r} = 2 \pi r^2. 
$$

---

However, when $h$ varies with $r$, its value $h=r$ must be substituted in *before* taking the derivative, so that *its* contribution to the rate of change of $V$ is included. In this case, the height also grows as the radius grows, so it's no surprise that the rate of change of the volume is greater. In this case, where $h=r$ and varies with it,
$$
V = \pi r^2 h = \pi r^3, 
$$
so
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}r} 
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \Bigl[ \pi r^3 \Bigr]
= 3 \pi r^2.
$$